# point to Git repository as source for Jenkins Job DSL job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have the option of file system or embedded script - how can I point to a Git repo?

[image]

I am asking specifically about the Job DSL not Multibranch Pipelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a standard SCM step to your job configuration. In that step, check out the needed repository and branch that contains the DSL script.

The "DSL Scripts" argument then has to point to the script that you checked out in that step.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can point it to a git repo using the `Process Job DSLs` build step. Instead if you use Job DSL in a pipeline script as described [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#use-job-dsl-in-pipeline-scripts) you can check out the repo first on to your job workspace and use the DSL script as target in your jobDsl build step