# How to let the Job DSL plugin fetch all jobs from remote Git instead of local file system?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to set up many jobs automatically. In the build step "Process Job DSLs", the `job-dsl` plugin allows to either "Use the provided DSL script" or "Look on Filesystem" for doing its thing. While "Look on Filesystem" looks like what I'm looking for, since it allows to define multiple Job DSL files at once, it sources them from a directory on the Jenkins server. I would rather have it fetch those job specifications from a remote Git repository.

Therefore, is it possible to source all jobs from a remote Git repository? Somehow like this pseudo code?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [point to git repo as source for jenkins job dsl job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840342/point-to-git-repo-as-source-for-jenkins-job-dsl-job)

Comment: I think this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840342/point-to-git-repo-as-source-for-jenkins-job-dsl-job) (and answered) before